# use dictionary keys to populate pandas field based on multi-condition test of other dataframe field using dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lambda

I want to add a column to dataframe (df) and populate using the keys from dictionary (d) based on a conditional test of df['val'] based on multiple values from d.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"val":list(range(0,10,1))})

val_dict = {'label1':(0,1),
            'label2':(2,4),
            'label3':(5,7),
            'label4':(8,10)
           }
```

I've got this working:

```
df['label'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: [k for k,v in val_dict.items() if (x <= v[1] and x >= v[0])][0])
```

To produce my expected output:

[image]

But it feels like too much of a hack and, for readability, I'd kinda prefer this:

```
def label_func(dct, fld):
    for k,v in dct.items():
        return np.select([(fld <= v[1]) and (fld >= v[0])], [k])

df['label2'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: label_func(val_dict, x))
```

but I just can't get it to work:

[image]

What am I missing?

This is my first attempt at building a more complex lambda function from scratch and I thought it should be really straightforward, but I haven't found my particular use case in other posts.  Thanks for help.

Note: I don't want to write a if/then statement because my dict will not always have the same number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.cut(df['val'], 
       [0,1,4,7,10], 
       labels = ['label1','label2','label3','label4'],
       include_lowest = True
       )
```

Note: googling "pandas bins" got me this function.